# Display x, y and z axis names next to each axis in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to display the names of the axis (of the TFs) next to each axis in rviz?

For example, if I remember correctly, the red axis should represent the x-axis, while the green axis should represent the y-axis. The problem is that I'm never sure about these conventions and having to look them up every time is a little bit tedious.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259883/display-x,-y-and-z-axis-names-next-to-each-axis-in-rviz/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2017-04-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's currently not possible. It also took me a while but once I realized that XYZ maps to RGB, it got pretty natural rather quickly.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4